How to find the length of a travel between planets using the Hohmann Transfer?
I am trying to figure out how long it would take to get from one planet to another. This is for a worldbuilding project of mine. I would put my question on the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange but I thought it would be better here.
The planet we start on is located at 1.3AU(The Perihelion is 1.274AU. The Aphelion is 1.326AU). It has a mass of $5.972 \times 10^{24}$ kg (1 Earth masses) and a radius of 6348.7 km.
The planet we are travelling to is located at 1.1AU(Perihelion of 1.097AU. Aphelion 1.103AU). The mass is $1.01524 \times 10^{25}$ kg (1.7 Earth masses), with a radius of 7250.74 km.
The star is $2.02878 \times 10^{30}$ (1.02 Solar masses).
If I need to add any more units I can. The Hohmann transfer formula is on this Wikipedia page.

That's just $t_H$ in your link, no?

We can answer your conceptual questions, but calculation-bssed questions are off-topic here. That example calculation on Wikipedia is for a simple transfer between circular orbits, in free space. It's more complicated with elliptical planet orbits, where the spacecraft is interacting with the gravity of the planets at each end of the transfer.

Also, you need the star's mass for these calculations. BTW, you should avoid working with masses in kg. Instead, use units like earth masses and solar masses. See my answer https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48616/16685 for details.

Can you add some clarity to this question?  You link the Wikipedia page for Hohmann transfers, which includes a section "Whether moving into a higher or lower orbit, by Kepler's third law, the time taken to transfer between the orbits is..." and then gives the equation to use.  This is the $t_H$ @Sten is mentioning.  Is there another aspect of this question not directly answered that page?

It seems you didn't see the wood for all the trees.
From the many number given in your question you only need these two:

The planet we start on is located at 1.3 AU.
The planet we are travelling to is located at 1.1 AU.

Then the semi-major axis of the Hohmann ellipse is
$$a_H=\frac{r_1+r_2}{2}
 = \frac{1.3\text{ AU}+1.1\text{ AU}}{2} = 1.2\text{ AU}$$
Now we can use the formula given in Hohmann transfer orbit -
Calculation to calculate the travel time
$$t_H=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4\pi^2a_H^3}{\mu}} \tag{1}$$
where
$$\mu=GM_\text{sun}=1.327\cdot 10^{20}\text{ m}^3\text{s}^{-2}$$
is the standard gravitational parameter
of the sun.
However, instead of expressing $\mu$ in meters and seconds
it is much more convenient to express it in AU and years.
$$\mu=4\pi^2\text{ AU}^3 \text{year}^{-2}$$
Finally insert the numbers into (1), notice that the $4\pi^2$
and AU$^3$ cancel and calculate the result.

Those two planets are not in our Solar System, so we probably shouldn't assume their star has the same mu as our Sun.

@PM2Ring Well, the question didn't specify anything about the star
(especially not its mass). So I thought it is our sun.

@PM2Ring You are correct. I forgot to add the different star mass. But it isn't too hard to find the GM of my star. I found it to be 1.35406864x10^20.  (I don't know how to fix my equations

I am still confused. I understand how you got the numbers but I don't know how I am meant to turn the GM into years. If I cancel out the $AU^3$ and $4π^2$, wouldn't it be 1.327?

GM is always in units of length^3 divided by time^2.  One can express this using SI units as m3/s2 as is done in the first equation after (1). I'd be a bit wary of doing the unit rephrasing Thomas recommends because your sun and our sun are so close together (they only differ by 2%), so it would be very easy to accidentally use the wrong meaning of year.  Thomas' obseration is that if you use a unit of length tied to the orbit of a planet around the sun, and use a unit of time tied to the orbit of the sun, several of the constants cancel out nicely.

In our case (in our solar system), we like to use Earth's orbital radius (1 AU) and Earth's orbital period (1 year).  They're convenient for us.  Once picking these units (AU and year), we can express the motion of any body in the solar system using the simplified equation (with lots of things canceled out) simply by converting that body's orbital radius and period into AU and years.

In your case, you appear to be the Earth-centric unit of AUs.  If you also use the Earth-centric units of Earth-years, you almost get to use the simplified equation but you'll have to corretly handle the 2% difference.  AU and Years are correctly scaled for our planet, but will not be scaled for yours.  They'll be 2% off... or 2% squared, or something like that.  You would need to correctly propagate that difference in M through the equations.  However, my experience is that when humans are working with units that almost make sense, they're likely to make intuitive errors.

Sticking to SI units (meters and seconds) means you stick to a unit that is so far away from any convenient scale that you're really forced to just churn through the equations rather than trying to cleverly skip steps.  The result will be a bit more work, but you're less likely to second-guess yourself into an error.

@Martamo Ok, but if your star is exactly 1.02 solar masses then its GM is ~1.353666888e20 m^3/s^2. You should work out the year length of your two planets, and also their synodic period (the time between oppositions) because that tells you how often you can perform a Hohmann transfer. Because your planets have fairly similar year lengths, the synodic period is quite large, much longer than the Hohmann transfer time.

@PM2Ring Using $$t_H=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4\pi^2a_H^3}{\mu}}$$ I do this $$t_H=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4\pi^21.2^3}{1.353666888x10^{20}}}$$ I got $3.549489035x10^{-10}$ That seems very wrong.

@Martamo That $\mu$ uses units of $\rm{m^3/s^2}$. So $a$ must be in metres, and $t_H$ will be in seconds.

@PM2Ring Oh, thank you. I was very confused.  $$t_H=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4\pi^2{1.795x10^{11}}^3}{1.353666888x10^{20}} }$$ I get $2.0553480812x10^7$ This equals 237.67 days.

But which mode of transportation is this based off of? Wikipedia simply states that it is "the time taken to transfer between the orbits". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit#Calculation
